# Retrieve JSON documents with a certain month and year in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve some documents from a collection in my MongoDB instance.
Here you are the entire collection:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("65708c6237b62067296a398f"),
    date: ISODate("2020-09-15T04:07:05.000Z"),
    description: 'playstation',
    category: 'miscellaneous',
    cost: 499,
    users: [ { username: 'Giacomo', amount: 499 } ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6570950cecb7eb1b4b868409"),
    date: ISODate("2020-09-15T04:07:05.000Z"),
    description: 'tennis court',
    category: 'sport',
    cost: 100,
    users: [
      { username: 'prova', amount: 50 },
      { username: 'Giacomo', amount: 50 }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6570953aecb7eb1b4b86840a"),
    date: ISODate("2023-02-09T03:12:15.012Z"),
    description: 'netflix subscription',
    category: 'entertainment',
    cost: 100,
    users: [ { username: 'prova', amount: 10 } ]
  }
]
```

At the moment, I can retrieve documents with a certain year as a part of the value of `date` with the following query:

```
  db
    .collection("expenses")
    .find({
      "users.username": "desired_username",
      $expr: { $eq: [{ $year: "$date" }, 2020] },
    })
```

As the next step, I want to retrieve documents that have not only a certain year but a certain month too (e.g. september, 2020 should return the first two documents). I don't know how to use two different expressions in the query.

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance for your patience.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/hpcSvUhWwQf like this?

Comment: also can u try https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ofc_qjmItGz  might need mongo 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in simplest terms you could have something like

```js
db.collection("expenses").find({
  "users.username": "desired_username",
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      { $eq: [{ $year: "$date" }, 2020] },
      { $eq: [{ $month: "$date" }, 9] }
    ]
  }
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hpcSvUhWwQf)

or if you want more fancy you could go with something like this with date to string formatting ([need mongo 7](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#format-specifiers) to use `%B` and get month names)

```js
db.collection("expenses").find({
  "users.username": "desired_username",
  $expr: {
      { $eq: [{ $dateToString: { format: "%B, %Y", date: "$date" } }, "september, 2020"] }  
  }
})
```

this will not work in mongoplayground since it runs on a lower mongo version

or something that might run on older versions like

```
db.collection("expenses").find({
  "users.username": "Giacomo",
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      { $eq: [{ $year: "$date" }, 2020] },
      {
        $eq: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              ["", "january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"],
              { $month: "$date" }
            ]
          },
          "september"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vOxnoAG2qq_)

okay one last just for fun but i guess this is too much making the query hard to understand at times ( this is exactly the longer version of what is shown in 2nd approach)

```js
db.collection("expenses").find({
  "users.username": "Giacomo",
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $concat: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              ["", "january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"],
              { $month: "$date" }
            ]
          },
          ", ",
          { $toString: { $year: "$date" } }
        ]
      },
      "september, 2020"
    ]
  }
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KLVdBlkyR3g)

Comment: I like the Format Specifiers. Not seen this before.

Comment: @jQueeny yeah it looks new (the month names at least). i also found out recently

Comment: Actually, if we just use `%m` for formatting the month, we don't require MongoDB v7.0+. MongoDB v3.0+ should be fine

Comment: @ray my bad i actually meant the month names

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach which you could modify is to leverage the `$gt`, `$gte`, `$lt` and `$lte` comparison operators to specify a start and end date from which to narrow your query. Below we have greater than or equal to 1st Sept 2020 but less than the 1st Oct 2020:

```js
db.collection("expenses").find({
   'users.username': 'desired_username',
   'date': {
      $gte: ISODate("2020-09-01"), 
      $lt: ISODate("2020-10-01")
   }
});
```

Comment: The ISODate is the number of milliseconds since epoch, and the time part defaults to 00:00, so `$lte: ISODate("2020-09-30")` would exclude anything after 00:00:00 on 30 Sep.  To make sure you get that whole day, use `$lt: ISODate("2020-10-01")`

Comment: Also note that this query could make use of a index on the date field.

Comment: @Joe thank you. Yes it would need to be less than 00:00:00 on 01 Oct 2020 then. Answer updated.